# How to validate user inputs in angular formly datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

im using angular-formly on my project.  we are allow user to pick date from DP (max:today min:today - 100 years) but user can also edit date in input field. So my question is how to allow user edit date only in range (from today yo today -100 years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the angular-formly UI Datepicker example. Is this what you mean by "DP"?

http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-datepicker

If you're having the user edit the date text as well, then I would suggest having you use an Angular filter as well as date text validation. Here's a really good example for what you need:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

If you want your dates to be now - 100 years, set the min to:

```
<input type="date"
   min="{{myMin}}">
```

where your controller would have a variable setting the min date

```
$scope.myMin = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 100);
```

It's untested but you may have to do some "toString" function.

Comment: yes DP (datepicker), yea user choose date from date picker but if he edit the date after picking i need to validate that input

Comment: I updated the second link. It will allow you to set a min and max date on your form. :)

Comment: i will  try it tomorrow. but looks really good. you are my Hero. thanks